# $scope with dot (.) not initializing values to input fields in angular

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

In my form:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="init('<%=JSON.stringify(data)%>')">
    <input type="text" ng-model="Reg.email" />
</div>
```

In my angular controller

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$parse', function($scope, $http, $parse) {
    $scope.init = function(myJsonData){
        if(myJsonData!=null)
        {
            var myData = angular.fromJson(myJsonData);
            $scope.Reg.email            = "test@example.com";
        }
    };
}]);
```

The above code will not initialize the values to the input field. But if i change model name by removing the **Reg.**  the code will work fine.

ie. **$scope.email** is working and **$scope.Reg.email** not working in my case.

Please support !

Comment: are you getting any error in console like Cannot set property 'email' of undefined as $scope.Reg is undefined?

Comment: ya got error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.init .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of `$scope.Reg`?

JavaScript throws error when you try to access any property of undefined variable or property. Here `$scope.Reg` is not defined, you need to first set $scope.Reg={} if it is not defined. Then you can use Value of $scope.Reg and its properties in templates and JavaScript code as well.

> **Note:** AngularJS don't throw any such error if you try to access property of undefined variable or property from angular templates.

In your case Reg property is not defined when init() gets called. Angular defines properties if it is not defined for any setter methods like ng-model.

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$parse', function($scope, $http, $parse) {
    $scope.Reg=$scope.Reg||{}; // Define if not defined
    $scope.init = function(myJsonData){
        if(myJsonData!=null)
        {
            var myData = angular.fromJson(myJsonData);
            $scope.Reg.email            = "test@example.com";
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue occured because you didn't define `$scope.Reg` object.

Define object like `$scope.Reg = {};`

Working plnkr [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/mcRJwf2Jgg3P2XziCNOx)

please check hope this is help you.

Answer (score 1):

If `$scope.Reg` is undefined then first initialize it by `$scope.Reg = {}` then access properties of `$scope.Reg`